# CSV formatting based on values

Tags: powershell, csv

[image]

I have a CSV file as above.

For each value of fruit name I want to check if the "color" and "size" value exists from top to bottom.

If both values exist then I want to copy the same values to the rows below it until I see another value. Once the other value is found then the next empty cells should use the updated value.

Example in the attached image row 2 and 3 will use value from row 1 for color and size columns. Then row 5 will use values from row 4.

The values for color and size should only be copied to the rows below it only after the first value is found. If no  value is found then both the color and size column can be empty like the example "grape". How can I do this for all such rows in a CSV file ?

Comment: Which application (Word, LibreOffice Writer, etc) or what programming language do you want to use?

Comment: I am currently creating this CSV file with PowerShell and viewing it with MS excel.